# PHP - escape backslash doesn't work

Tags: php, wamp

Well the title sums it up. If I do this:

```
fwrite($handle, 'test\r\ntest');
```

I get **litreally** that written to a file. That is:

```
test\r\ntest
```

It doesn't work for echo or any other function manipulates strings.

This became a problem when I needed to write to a printer in the serial port using ESC/POS. If I use PHP, it prints a bunch of question makrs and french characteres. With Python (plus pyserial), using the following code, works amazingly:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM4');

ser.write('\x1b\x40');
ser.write('\x0a');
ser.write('\x0a');
ser.write('Hello there');
ser.write('\x0a');
ser.write('\x1d\x56\x42\x03');
```

My system:
WAMP 2.4 (PHP 5.4.16, Apache 2.4.4) on Windows 7 Home Basic x64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the backslash sign to escape special characters you need to use double-quoted strings, not single-quoted ones, try these :

```
fwrite($handle, 'test\r\ntest'); // not working
fwrite($handle, "test\r\ntest"); // works as expected
```

It may be worth noting that the problem could have been skipped altogether if your data came from another source (non-php file, web form), and happens only when you hardcode your strings inside your script file. For further details, feel free to browse the relevant manual page :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 4):

Using a single quote will literally write your string.
To use escaped characters you need to use a double quote instead :

```
echo "This output will \n expand";
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I realized that the quotes were wrong, thank you. That means the problem is not there, since it still doesn't write correctly to serial port (unlike python).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `"` instead of `'` for these escape sequences:

```
fwrite($handle, "test\r\ntest");
```